# New user is not getting authenticated in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I created a new user in mongo console using the below command.

```
db.createUser(
 {
  user: "admin",
  pwd: "admin",
  roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "admin" } ]
 }
);
```

The response for the above command:

```
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
            {
                    "role" : "dbOwner",
                    "db" : "admin"
            }
    ]
 }
```

Once created, I am trying to login into the db using the below command:

```
mongo --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "admin" -p "admin"
```

But the authentication failed with the below message:

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I tried with different dbs and different users as well. Nothing works

Comment: before creating the user did you set your database context?  For example, the first command should be `use admin` - so it will match your connection string?  I suspect you created your user in the database 'test' which is the default if none is specified.  You can verify this theory by changing your connection string to `mongo --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "test" -u "admin" -p "admin"`

Comment: @barrypicker You are right. I didn't set the context. It works after I set the context to a DB. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you are not using interactive shell, you may want to use `db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser(...)`.